# Conflict duplicating element ID's during conditional statements?

Tags: validation, conditional-statements

```
<a href="index.html"><!--[if gte IE 9]><!--><img src="images/logo.svg" onerror="this.src=images/logo.png;this.onerror=null;" id="logo" alt="Sample logo"><!--<![endif]--><!--[if lt IE 9]><img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" alt="Sample logo"><![endif]--></a>
```

Will this validate properly since the same ID tag is used twice on the same page because one is used in a conditional statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="index.html"><!--[if gte IE 9]><img src="images/logo.svg" onerror="this.src=images/logo.png;this.onerror=null;" id="logo" alt="Sample logo"><![endif]><!--[if lt IE 9]><img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" alt="Sample logo"><![endif]></a>
```

Try this code. I saw some extra tags in your code which I have removed.